# Month value is skipped inside loop

Tags: javascript

I have a function `generateMonths()` which ideally needs to generate an array of objects having month's information as:

```
[{id: "2020-01", name: "Jan-2020"}, {id: "2020-02", name: "Feb-2020"},...]
```

Problem is the below code always skipping the Month of **February**.

```js
const MONTH_MAPPER = {
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Feb',
  3: 'Mar',
  4: 'Apr',
  5: 'May',
  6: 'Jun',
  7: 'Jul',
  8: 'Aug',
  9: 'Sep',
  10: 'Oct',
  11: 'Nov',
  12: 'Dec',
};

function generateMonths() {
  const newDate = new Date();
  const months = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    console.log('newDate', newDate.getMonth());
    const date = new Date(newDate.setMonth((newDate.getMonth() + 1)));
    console.log('date', date.getMonth());
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    months.push({
      id: `${year}-${month < 10 ? '0'+ month : month}`,
      name: `${MONTH_MAPPER[month]}-${year}`
    });
  }
  return months;
}

console.log(generateMonths())
```

Here is working [Fiddle of the same](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh8fse5w/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem is related to the month day that is used by default... (print the generated date to check it) you are going to have problems, specially today ;) (today is day 30 and february doesn't have that day).

Change the day to 1 with newDate.setDate(1); on the generated date objects, here, this should work:

```
function generateMonths() {
  const newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setDate(1);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik `new Date()` gives you a Date instance for **today** (or any particular day when you run the code).  Today is 30 December, and there is no day 30 in February.

Comment: Elaborated in the answer. Also I have to say that the line: const date = new Date(newDate.setMonth((newDate.getMonth() + 1))); even it should work, I and think I understand why you used it... it's kind weirdo and ugly XD ;) dont'?

Comment: Maaaybe you can change the loop to for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { and that should simply your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a for loop which iterates 12 times and you know you want months from 1 to 12, then why use getMonths? By seeing your output, I guess the below code helps.

```
function generateMonths() {

    const newDate = new Date();
    const months = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        const year = newDate.getFullYear() + 1;
        months.push({
            id: `${year}-${i < 10 ? '0' + i : i}`,
            name: `${MONTH_MAPPER[i]}-${year}`
        });
    }
    return months;
}

console.log(generateMonths())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem when the current month is 11...

```
const date = new Date(newDate.setMonth((newDate.getMonth() + 1)));
```

You're setting the month to 12, which is outside the range of months in JS (which is 0-11)

According to documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

*If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMonth() attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.*

Answer (score 0):

@user1039663's answer is correct, but it would be beneficial here not to rely on mutating `Date` objects.

```js
const MONTH_MAPPER = {
  1: 'Jan',
  2: 'Feb',
  3: 'Mar',
  4: 'Apr',
  5: 'May',
  6: 'Jun',
  7: 'Jul',
  8: 'Aug',
  9: 'Sep',
  10: 'Oct',
  11: 'Nov',
  12: 'Dec',
};

function generateMonths() {

  const year = new Date().getFullYear()
  const months = [];

  for (let month in MONTH_MAPPER) {
    months.push({
      id: `${year}-${month < 10 ? '0'+ month : month}`,
      name: `${MONTH_MAPPER[month]}-${year}`
    });
  }
  return months;
}

console.log(generateMonths())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is because February has 28 or 29 days

```
var jan312020 = new Date(2020, 1-1, 31);
var oneMonthFromJan312020 = new Date(new Date(jan312020).setMonth(jan312020.getMonth()+1));
console.log("Jan 2020 : "+ jan312020);
console.log("Jan 2020 : "+ oneMonthFromJan312020)
```

The output will be :

```
'Jan 2020 : Fri Jan 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'
'Jan 2020 : Mon Mar 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'
```

If you will set the day of the month to the first of January then you will get the right result.

```
 var jan312020 = new Date(2020, 1-1, 1);
var oneMonthFromJan312020 = new Date(new Date(jan312020).setMonth(jan312020.getMonth()+1));
console.log("Jan 2020 : "+ jan312020);
console.log("Jan 2020 : "+ oneMonthFromJan312020)
```

And then the output will be:

```
'Jan 2020 : Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'
'Jan 2020 : Sat Feb 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'
```